# Add svg to web page?

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I add an svg to my webpage and change it's color via css?

I've tried:

```
<img src="my.svg" class="svg"/>

.svg{
    fill: white;
}
```

But no luck.

CSS only solutions please, and I do not need any fallbacks, only supporting new browsers.

Comment: There are many ways of including a SVG, take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg. It's important to say that some ways may look easier (like using a `<img>` tag as you did or using it as a `background-image`) but it just causes the problem you are facing: impossibility to cascade external CSS inside the SVG, i.e. the page's styling isn't reflected inside the loaded SVG.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work this way. You can change the fill color if you're directly including the svg, i.e.:

HTML:

```
<p>Some other webpage content</p>
<svg class="my-svg">
    <g>
        <path fill="..."></path>
        <path fill="..."></path>
    </g>
</svg>
<p>Some other webpage content</p>
```

CSS:

```
.my-svg *{
    fill:white;
}
```

So, you web-inspect `my.svg`, and copy-paste its contents to the destination page. Then you can style it.